# Responsive CSS column

Tags: html, css, api, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a two-columns layout. Main content column contains the blog card and the second column which I'm trying to place at the top right corner contains.

[This](https://codepen.io/ChynoDeluxe/pen/bdXeqQ) is the blog card.

The Bootstrap layout I'm using:

```
<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="blog-card">
        <div class="meta">
          <div class="photo" style="background-image: url({{ post.featured_image }})"></div>
          <ul class="details">
            <li class="author"><a href="#">John Doe</a></li>
            <li class="date">Aug. 24, 2015</li>
            <li class="tags">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
          <h2>Opening a door to the future</h2>
          <p>{{post.summary}}</p>
          <p class="read-more">
            <a href="{{ url_for('blog.show_post', slug=post.slug) }}">Read More</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content-section">
        <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
        <p class='text-muted'>
          You can put any information here you'd like.
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
          </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

The `col-md-4` content doesn't stick to the right on desktop view, it just appears at the bottom of the card. I've tried several methods but it doesn't work. I'm actually calling an API and using the blog card to display posts from the CMS I am using. Instead of the sidebar to remain at the top right with the first post it sticks to the last post.

Comment: Verify the validity of your markup (you probably have a typo somewhere). As you can see [here](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/ZEzMYKa), it works. If you can't pinpoint the error yourself, you need to provide a [mcve] in the question itself so that the error can be inspected by anyone able to help.

Comment: i need to fix the sidebar content at the top right corner, whenever i call the api it brings a list of my blog posts that are on my CMS. so i am using only one card as the template for which the posts will appear. The sidebar content sticks to the last post which is at the bottom of the page and not the first post.

Comment: Then do not place it inside a `col` at all. Position it using `position: fixed;`.

Comment: if i remove the column,it wouldn't be responsive anymore

Comment: Use `position: fixed` inside a `@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) { ... }` (for `lg`). Or have your pick from Bootstrap's [responsive breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I want it to be the same height as the blog post. That's why I tried to put it in a column in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got it to work: I made the sidebar show only on certain screen sizes. Although, my blog card gets scattered, I am okay with the outcome.

Instead of using columns, media queries did the trick:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1020px) and (max-width: 3000px)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `container` class in main tag. This class has `max-width` and `padding` from `left` and `right`. If you want use 100% of the page use `container-fluid` class.

```
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" style="border:solid 1px red">
      {% blog %}{% card html }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border:solid 1px red">
      <div class="content-section">
        <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
        <p class='text-muted'>
          You can put any information here you'd like.
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
          </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>`
```

Comment: Not what i am looking for, i have ,kindly check my earlier replies and i have edited the code.